# ASP.net ViewState encryption and decryption

Tags: asp.net, security, viewstate

I heard that .NET framework will encrypt the ViewState using SHA1 or some other algorithm.
So if i know the SHA1 encryption and decryption algorithm can i tamper a ViewState?I mean
a malicious user studies SHA1 encryption algorithm,if he understand that algorith and develops decryption algorithm ,will it open the road of viewstate tampering? or SHA1 or other algorithm uses any random tricks for encryption and decryption?

Comment: SHA1 is a hash algorithm.  At the very most, it could be used to make sure the viewstate hasn't been tampered with (and even then, only if some secret server-side string were included in the hash).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Encryption implies a key.  Said key is kept on the server, and (barring other, much bigger, security issues) the client never sees it.  Without knowing that key, you aren't even going to be able to view encrypted viewstate, much less change it.

Even without encryption, the server can be told to generate a hash of the viewstate and a key that only the server knows.  Without knowing that key, you can still read the viewstate, but you won't be able to edit it without a whole lot of effort.

Now, it's possible that whatever encryption or hashing algorithm the framework uses, could be broken enough to make tampering easy.  But if it were, you'd hear about it pretty quickly -- as that same algorithm will be used in dozens of other places (there are a few well-known, well-tested algorithms that just about everyone uses).

**Short version:** If you care about preventing tampering, the stuff built into ASP.net will work pretty well if configured properly.

Comment: Wha is the difference between encoding and encryting?

Comment: @ishagoel: Encoding doesn't involve a key, and is designed to be easily reversible (Base64 is an example of encoding; anyone can decode and thus view it).  Encryption, not so much -- it's only reversible if you have the right key.  Cryptographic hashing is a whole different thing; it's designed not to be reversible *at all*.  The most you can do with a hash is take the data it was made from and re-hash it (using the same salt you used originally), and compare the hash to the one you already have.  With salt, it works pretty well to defend against tampering.

Comment: @well explained ! Thank you.I accepted your answer.Have a nice day